# How to set no-cache headers to a specific url using htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cache

I have a wordpress website that is using the wp default .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php?nocache [L]
</IfModule>
```

My needs is to set the `no-cache` header just for the posts that begin with the same url, for example:

```
example.com/content/category_to_not_be_cached/foo_post
example.com/content/category_to_not_be_cached/bar_post
```

but i dont get how to do that using the .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from [Apache mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) documentation:

```
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache env=CGI
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache env=NO_CACHE
Header merge Cache-Control no-store env=NO_STORE
```

This could be wrapped in a `<Directory>` block or a series of `<File>` blocks to accommodate your needs (providing your host has enabled mod_headers).

Comment: Yes but i dont have to face with phisical files or directory, but with path aliases...

Comment: ...but the Location directive, is what i was looking for! thanks